# Names for camera moves

Tags: opengl, 3d, camera, language-agnostic, terminology

I've got a 3D scene and want to offer an API to control the camera. The camera is currently described by its own position, a look-at point in the scene somewhere along the *z* axis of the camera frame of reference, an “up” vector describing the *y* axis of the camera frame of reference, and a field-of-view angle. I'd like to provide at least the following operations:

### Two-dimensional operations (mouse drag or arrow keys)

- Keep look-at point and rotate camera around that. This can also feel like rotating the object, with the look-at point describing its centre. I think that at some point I've heard this described as the camera “orbiting” around the centre of the scene.
- Keep camera position, and rotate camera around that point. Colloquially I'd call this “looking around”. With a cinema camera this might perhaps be called pan and tilt, but in 3d modelling “panning” is usually something else, see below. Using aircraft principal directions, this would be a pitch-and-yaw movement of the camera.
- Move camera position and look-at point in parallel. This can also feel like translating the object parallel to the view plane. As far as I know this is usually called “panning” in 3d modelling contexts.

### One-dimensional operations (e.g. mouse wheel)

- Keep look-at point and move camera closer to that, by a given factor. This is perhaps what most people would consider a “zoom” except for those who know about real cameras, see below.
- Keep all positions, but change field-of-view angle. This is what a “real” zoom would be: changing the focal length of the lens but nothing else.
- Move both look-at point and camera along the line connecting them, by a given distance. At first this feels very much like the first item above, but since it changes the look-at point, subsequent rotations will behave differently. I see this as complementing the last point of the 2d operations above, since together they allow me to move camera and look-at point together in all three directions. The cinema camera man might call this a “dolly” shot, but I guess a dolly might also be associated with the other translation moves parallel to the viewing plane.
- Keep look-at point, but change camera distance from it and field-of-view angle in such a way that projected sizes in the plane of the look-at point remain unchanged. This would be a dolly zoom in cinematic contexts, but might also be used to adjust for the viewer's screen size and distance from screen, to make the field-of-view match the user's environment.
- Rotate around *z* axis in camera frame of reference. Using aircraft principal directions, this would be a roll motion of the camera. But it could also feel like a rotation of the object within the image plane.

What would be a consistent, unambiguous, concise set of function names to describe all of the above operations? Perhaps something already established by some existing API?

Comment: I would go with real world camera analogies. The only thing I can think of that cannot be expressed in the real world is the orthogonal projection, with which you cannot use a camera position, a focal length, or a fov. You probably won't need this if what you are trying do to is render a photorealistic scene.

Comment: That being said, there is a lot of public APIs that gives the control to the camera and they already use names like Yaw, Pitch, LookAt, UpVector, FOV, MoveAlongDir (I'm sure there is a better name ), Pan. I found several examples that do pretty much what you are trying to achieve. Try googling "OpenGL Camera Class"

Comment: Look to the movie world. They use the term "Dolly" for when the camera is on a track and moves forwards and backwards or side to side, for example - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_dolly. Though dolly tracks can be curved so there's not a 1:1 correspondence with what you want to do.